# Hi, How do I show 2nd highest paid employees city wise with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I show 2nd highest-paid employees city wise with `mysql`
I have 2 tables
Employeedetails with empid, fullname, city
and
emloyeesalary with empid, salary
I need a query that shows me 2nd highest paid employee per each city

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT ED.EMPID,ED.FullName,ED.City ,ES.Salary,
   DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ED.CITY ORDER BY ES.Salary Desc) AS Rnk
FROM Employeedetails ED INNER JOIN EmployeeSalary ON ED.EMPID=ES.EMPID
)
SELECT FullName
FROM T
WHERE Rnk=2;
```